# Using a function to validate email-addresses

Tags: php

I'm new to custom functions in PHP. I'm using the following function, from a book, to validate email addresses:

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];

function is_email($email) {
// Checks for proper email format
    if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&\'*+-/=?ˆ_`{|}~]+@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)+[A-Za-z]%/', $email)) 
    {
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
       return true;
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Validate Email</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    Email<input type="text" name="email"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to show a message if the email was correct, and show a message if it wasn't correct. I don't really know know what to do next. I've already tried the following, before the ?> closing tag:

```
if (is_email($email) == true) {
    echo "Right";
}
elseif (is_email($email) == false) {
    echo "Wrong";
}
```

But this doesn't do anything. What's the solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to answer to such a question. There are quite some details missing, we don't know your real setup. I suggest you try to find out yourself what's up. That is not that difficult and it will help you understand how php scripts work in a web environment. Try this: When you click the submit button, what happens? One step after another. Try to show each step by adding debug output, into a logfile preferably.

Comment: Is you question about validating email addresses or is it about print variables from PHP?

Comment: No, more how to show if the email was in the correct format or not

Comment: That % at the end of the regular expression looks suspicious, anyway I'd rather see a $ there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll I'm not 100% sure what exactly is causing your issues here, but allow me to provide another way to validate emails within a custom function. You really don't have to re-invent the wheel because there is already a native PHP method to validate emails.

```
function validateEmail($email){
  return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}

$email = $_POST['email'];
if (validateEmail($email)){
  echo 'Valid email!';
}else{
  echo 'Email NOT valid!';
}
```

I'm using the [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) method here with a [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: That's an even better example. I editted the if-statement though. It was _if (validate($email))_, but it should be _if (validateEmail($email))_ ;) Thanks.

Comment: @b.s - true true. My mistake... Thanks for the feedback! I would always prefer a native method if it exists (as in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your regular expression is correct? I modified it and I was able to get the code working.

```
<?php

function is_email($email) {
    // Checks for proper email format

    if (!preg_match("/\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", $email)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (is_email($email) == true) {
        echo "Right";
    } elseif (is_email($email) == false) {
        echo "Wrong";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working. Strange, because the regular expressions I used came straight from the example I used.

Answer (score 0):

...

```
if (is_email($email)) {
    $valid="Right";
} else {
    $valid="Wrong";
}
?>
```

...

```
<body><?php echo($valid); ?>
```

Comment: @B.S. Hey, trying to help, without many clues, anyway this is the correct way of writing it if you don't want it to be before the `<!DOCTYPE html><html>`. Thanks for downvoting! Now solve it yourself.

Comment: The downvote is mine. Take a look at your code again. You are executing the `is_email` function twice and expecting different results... If the email is valid the function will return `true` twice... Please take the time to test your code before posting it. If you don't have the time to test it - please state that it is untested code. This code is simply wrong...

Comment: @Lix Ok, sorry you are right, just did some copy paste too quick

Answer (score 0):

I recommand [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), builtin php. So I think this function will be kept in future, whereas regexp function can change for instance.

Moreover, you can say "it's the role of the language to assume that this function works good, not mine".

```
<?php
var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
```